# Revert a Feature Component programmatically

Tags: 7, features

I have a Feature installed using an Installation Profile. But I always have to go and Revert a particular Component so that it's no longer Overridden (so that, for example, the Feature's Blocks appear).  I just wanted to know if I can take this step programmatically using code itself in the Installation Profile.

In the screenshot below, I've shown the component that has to be reverted programmatically (in the screenshot, it's already reverted back so check box is not available).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I'm willing to bet that if you spend some time in the issue queue, you will find out _why_ it starts as reverted. If there isn't a patch available, atleast you will be closer to understanding where you need to attack the problem.

Comment: @Letharion - But these are all custom blocks and views developed.

Comment: By that definition, _everything_ you export would be "custom", so that doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could solve the issue by using the hook function `fe_block_settings_features_revert('basic_site')` where fe_block_settings is the hook i.e. the component here and basic_site is the feature/module name.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? how do you use this function in .profile or .install ?

Answer (score 20):

Here are a few thoughts though on resetting your features programmatically or as add-on install scripts.

You could use Drush to reset the [Feature](http://drupal.org/project/features):

`drush features-revert [feature name]`

Another thought would be to use [features_revert](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!features!features.module/function/features_revert/7)() during the install process:

`features_revert(array('module' => array('component')));`

The [Strongarm](http://drupal.org/project/strongarm) module could be useful as well to [force](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/dec/04/strongarm-2-leaner-and-meaner/) your [Feature](http://drupal.org/project/features) to retain its default state I think.

*I have to agree with @Letharion in his comment on your OP.  I would want to know that other important things aren't being mistakenly modified during the install process.*

Answer (score 18):

You can revert a single features module with [features_revert_module()](http://api.drupal.psu.edu/api/drupal/modules!contrib!features!features.module/function/features_revert_module/mooc7).

```
features_revert_module('my_feature');
```

Answer (score 16):

Revert ALL components in feature

```
$feature = features_get_features('my_feature_machine_name');
$components = array_keys($feature->info['features']);
features_revert(array('my_feature_machine_name' => $components));
```

Comment: I think features_revert_module('my_module'); does all these steps.

Answer (score 5):

```
features_revert(array('module' => array('component')));
```

Where 'module' is the name of the specific features module (i.e. the the module generated when you download the feature) and 'component' are the components of those features. So if you just want to revert the fields defined in the feature you can use 'field' for component.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`features_revert()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!features!features.module/function/features_revert/7) to revert specific components only where the syntax is:

```
features_revert(array($module => $components));
```

for example:

```
features_revert(array('module_name' => array('taxonomy', 'node')));
```

To revert the whole module (with all its components), then use [`features_revert_module()`](http://api.drupal.psu.edu/api/drupal/modules!contrib!features!features.module/function/features_revert_module/mooc7) instead, for example:

```
features_revert_module('module_name');
```

---

#### Rules

For rules, this method is much quicker (to revert single rule):

```
$rule_name = 'my_custom_rule';
if ($rule = rules_config_load($rule_name)) {
  $rule->delete();
}
```

To revert all rules, it's:

```
if ($rules = rules_config_load_multiple(FALSE)) {
  foreach($rules as $rule) {
    if ($rule->hasStatus(ENTITY_OVERRIDDEN) && !$rule->hasStatus(ENTITY_FIXED)) {
      $rule->delete();
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>See: [Add drush rules-revert [#2474577] | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/2474577)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

To revert all overridden components of all Features in your Installation Profile, add the following to your .profile file's hook_profile_tasks():

```
/**
 * Rebuild & Revert all enabled features.
 */
features_rebuild();
features_revert();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Reverts all components of a feature.
     */
    function YOURMODULE_helpers_install_features_revert($module, $component = NULL) {
      module_load_include('inc', 'features', 'features.export');
      features_include();
      if (($feature = feature_load($module, TRUE)) && module_exists($module)) {
        $components = array();
        if (is_null($component)) {
          // Forcefully revert all components of a feature.
          foreach (array_keys($feature->info['features']) as $component) {
            if (features_hook($component, 'features_revert')) {
              $components[] = $component;
            }
          }
        }
        else {
          // Use the $component argument of this function.
          $components[] = $component;
        }
        foreach ($components as $component) {
          features_revert(array($module => array($component)));
        }

        drush_print(format_string('Reverted "!module" feature components !components.', array(
          '!module' => $module,
          '!components' => implode(', ', $components),
        )));
      }
      else {
        drush_print(format_string('Unable to revert "!module" feature.', array('!module' => $module)));
      }
    }
```