# How to always run hook_update_N automatically, regardless of the 'N' value?

Tags: updating

I need to run a specific command after each update of a certain module. Is there any way to use `hook_update_N` without having to update the `N` for each version? A `hook_update_always` solution?

The use case is that I have Features with Rules. These Rules are not always reverted to the new version when the Feature is updated. If I can have a revert/delete function to run after every update of this Feature/module it would save me some headache.

Comment: Sorry, but this is really difficult to understand. Could you please provide some sample case and clarify?

Comment: I've updated the question with my use case.

Comment: You are actually looking for a deployment routine, aren't you?

Comment: Are you executing "drush fr my-feature" or equivalent? If the rule isn't being reverted this is a bug in features and that's what you should be focussing on.

Comment: @leymannx : We are doing prototypes with Rules and Features. (It has proven to be much faster than ordinary 'git-routines'.) So - yes, this is a deployment related need, but it is the deployment during the development iterations.

Comment: @ Alfred Armstrong: No, this is not related to Drush. It is Drupal's internal behaviour.

Comment: @Alfred Armstrong: We are sometimes  working on sites where the site owner doesn't allow for manual access to the file system. Hence no Drush for us.

Comment: @Leiph your requirement is a bit confusing. Please explain in more detail the steps you are performing and what you want to happen.

Comment: In the module package, within the mymodule.install file, I'd like to place a function "mymodule_update_always". This function is to be called by Drupal core whenever the module is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all you have to do is to provide a custom module that implements `hook_update_N`, and everytime you want your features to be reverted, you add a new `hook_update_N` to your module time by time.

Starting with `hook_update_7001`, then `hook_update_7002`, then `hook_update_7003` etc. (presuming you are using D7).

On your live server then you have to run `drush updatedb`, it will check for the **newest** update functions and run the code that's put inside them.

And then there's [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/21501/15055) which already has a lot of answers to show you what to put inside your update function to revert a feature programmatically (skip the Drush answer).

---

How you set up your deploy routine then, that's totally up to you. Normally you would have a webhook or some continuous integration SaaS like [CircleCi](https://circleci.com/) setup to run a predefined deployment script **on every code release automatically**. This (Bash-)script then would run let's say `git pull`, `drush cc all`, `drush updb -y`, `drush fra -y` always automatically.

Comment: Nitpicking: It would be 7100, 7101, 7102 and so on - 7001, 7002 etc are designated for migrations from Drupal 6. Not that core actually cares, it'll run them anyway, but just for posterity

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't address my OP. I need - if possible - a static code to be placed in the mymodule.install-file.

Comment: @Leiph – Which doesn't exist (,yet). That's why we use deployment routines. But good luck anyways :)

Comment: No, that was obvious from the documentation. 

I was hoping that someone had managed to do a workaround. Add something to the update task list, or reset the schema counter during update, or something else.

But anyhow - thanks for your efforts.